# appcompat_v7 cannot re-import android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created an Android project in Eclipse, it automatically adds an "appcompat_v7" which looks like some backward compatibility library.

Then I created a new workspace, and tried to re-import the same exact projects. That dependency gets renamed to "android-support-v7-appcompat" and nothing build anymore with errors saying: 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Anyone knows how I get the rid of this dependency or a way to have my project rebuild normally?

thanks

Comment: Which api is your target sdk?

Comment: Set this android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229003/3922207. It might solve your problem.